# Search Double/Decimal number in Datatable using select statement c#

Tags: c#, select, search, datatable, decimal

I have a question about how to use `DataTable.Select` statement in C#.

I work on a program that uses `DataTables` as `DataSources` and now I am currently working on the search statement where I would like to use the `Select()` method.

The reason for this is that I want to make the user to be able to build a search query with multiple search options during the program runtime.

Generally everything works well , but if I want to search for a `Decimal` or `Double` number I get a search ERROR(and I check if the value exists).

This is a sample code of my code.

```
string Query = "";
string[][] columnname = ;this the 2d array where my table names are stored for building a query.

Double/Decimal Value = 10,15; current value where searching for as example.

Query = ColumnName[0][1] + " = " + Value;

DGV.DataSource = DT.Select(Query).CopyToDataTable();

Error Code//

System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: De expressie bevat een syntaxisfout.
   bij System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse()
   bij System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)
   bij System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression)
   bij HPIT_ProgrammingTool.Classes.FillinFormHeaderAndSearch.BuildRunQuery() in
```

Comment: "i got a search error": which error do you get?

Comment: Please give us a more detailed and well formatted code , because I fixed it but it is not understandable.

Comment: Wild guess: maybe the decimal separator in your query string is a comma instead of a dot?

Comment: {"De expressie bevat een syntaxisfout."} System.Data.SyntaxErrorException

Comment: i checked for the comma  or dot problem but in both situation i get the same error but when i search for integer there is no problem at all i checked for my datatypes of my datasource and for currencys it decimal and for commanumber its Double.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your decimal/double values are being converted to string using your current culture, which uses , as the decimal separator - [but DataTable expressions only support . which is culture-invariant](https://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

To fix this, first convert your decimal and double values to strings using the invariant culture:

```cs
string Query = "";
string[][] ColumnName = ...;

Double/Decimal Value = 10,15;

var stringValue = Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Query = ColumnName[0][1] + " = " + stringValue;

DGV.DataSource = DT.Select(Query).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ian it worked for my code. Thankyou for you time.